# How to merge DataFrames based on on column while adding another

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following mock DataFrames:

df1:

```
ID    FILLER1    FILLER2    QUANTITY

01      123        132         12
02      123        132         5
03      123        132         10
```

df2:

```
ID    FILLER1    FILLER2    QUANTITY

01      123        132         +1
02      123        132         -1
```

which would result in the 'Quantity' of DF1 will result in 13, 4 and 10.

Thx in advance for any help provided!

Comment: `df1.QUANTITY = df1.QUANTITY.add(df2.QUANTITY, fill_value=0)`?

Comment: the problem with this one is that I have the method bound to a button and if I do it like this it will keep subtracting from the quantity for every click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not super clear but if I get what you're trying to do here is a way:

```
# A left join and filling 0 instead of NaN for that third row
In [19]: merged = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID', 'FILLER1', 'FILLER2'], how='left').fillna(0)

In [20]: merged
Out[20]:
   ID  FILLER1  FILLER2  QUANTITY_x  QUANTITY_y
0   1      123      132          12         1.0
1   2      123      132           5        -1.0
2   3      123      132          10         0.0

# Adding new quantity column
In [21]: merged['QUANTITY'] = merged['QUANTITY_x'] + merged['QUANTITY_y']

In [22]: merged
Out[22]:
   ID  FILLER1  FILLER2  QUANTITY_x  QUANTITY_y  QUANTITY
0   1      123      132          12         1.0      13.0
1   2      123      132           5        -1.0       4.0
2   3      123      132          10         0.0      10.0

# Removing _x and _y columns
In [23]: merged = merged[['ID', 'FILLER1', 'FILLER2', 'QUANTITY']]

In [24]: merged
Out[24]:
   ID  FILLER1  FILLER2  QUANTITY
0   1      123      132      13.0
1   2      123      132       4.0
2   3      123      132      10.0
```

Comment: thx! Sorry for the unclearness. I am trying to make a program to update an inventory quantity with new arrivals